# in codeigniter 4 pagination only first page is displayed

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am new in codeigniter 4 and stuck in pagination i have a list of customers and in pagination first page is displaying 10 records properly but when i click page 2 button i get error message "The requested URL was not found on this server." can anyone help me
my controller is

```
<?php

  namespace App\Controllers;
  use App\Models\CustModel;

 class Main extends BaseController
 {   
protected $request;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->request = \Config\Services::request();
    $this->session = session();
    $this->cust_model = new CustModel;        
    $this->data = ['session' => $this->session,'request'=>$this->request];
}

public function index()
{
    $this->data['page_title']="Home";
    
    return view('pages/home', $this->data);
}

public function customers(){
    $this->data['page_title']="customers";
    $this->data['page'] =  !empty($this->request->getVar('page')) ? $this->request->getVar('page') : 1;
    $this->data['perPage'] =  10;
    $this->data['total'] =  $this->cust_model->countAllResults();
    $this->data['customers'] = $this->cust_model->paginate($this->data['perPage']);
    $this->data['total_res'] = is_array($this->data['customers'])? count($this->data['customers']) : 0;
    $this->data['pager'] = $this->cust_model->pager;
    return view('pages/customers/list', $this->data);
}
}
```

my model is

```
  <?php 
  namespace App\Models;

  use CodeIgniter\Model;

  class CustModel extends Model{

protected $DBGroup          = 'default';
protected $table            = 'customer';
protected $primaryKey       = 'id';
protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
protected $insertID         = 0;
protected $returnType       = 'array';
protected $useSoftDeletes   = false;
protected $protectFields    = true;
protected $allowedFields = ['name','fname','password', 'cnic','phone','age', 'gender', 'address'];

// Dates
protected $useTimestamps = false;
protected $dateFormat    = 'datetime';
protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';


// Validation
protected $validationRules      = [];
protected $validationMessages   = [];
protected $skipValidation       = false;
protected $cleanValidationRules = true;


protected $allowCallbacks = true;
protected $beforeInsert   = [];
protected $afterInsert    = [];
protected $beforeUpdate   = [];
protected $afterUpdate    = [];
protected $beforeFind     = [];
protected $afterFind      = [];
protected $beforeDelete   = [];
protected $afterDelete    = [];
```

my list page is

```
  <?= $this->extend('layouts/main') ?>
  <?= $this->section('content') ?>
  <div class="card rounded-0">
   <div class="card-header">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="card-title h4 mb-0 fw-bolder">List of customers</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <a href="<?= base_url('Main/user_add') ?>" class="btn btn btn-primary bg-gradient 
   border rounded-0"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i> Add customer</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <th class="p-1 text-center">id</th>
                <th class="p-1 text-center">Name</th>
                <th class="p-1 text-center">fname</th>
                <th class="p-1 text-center">cnic</th>
                <th class="p-1 text-center">phone</th>
                <th class="p-1 text-center">gender</th>
                <th class="p-1 text-center">age</th>
                <th class="p-1 text-center">address</th>                    
                <th class="p-1 text-center">Action</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($customers as $row): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="p-1 text-center align-middle"><?= $row['id'] ?></th>
                        <td class="px-2 py-1 align-middle"><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
                        <td class="px-2 py-1 align-middle"><?= $row['fname'] ?></td>
                        <td class="px-2 py-1 align-middle"><?= $row['cnic'] ?></td>
                        <td class="px-2 py-1 align-middle"><?= $row['phone'] ?></td>
                        <td class="px-2 py-1 align-middle"><?= $row['gender'] ?></td>
                        <td class="px-2 py-1 align-middle"><?= $row['age'] ?></td>
                        
                        <td class="px-2 py-1 align-middle"><?= $row['address'] ?></td>
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        <td class="px-2 py-1 align-middle text-center">
                            <a href="<?= base_url('Main/user_edit/'.$row['id']) ?>" class="mx-2 text-decoration-none text-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                            <a href="<?= base_url('Main/user_delete/'.$row['id']) ?>" class="mx-2 text-decoration-none text-danger" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure to delete <?= $row['id'] ?> from list?') !== true) event.preventDefault()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php if(count($customers) <= 0): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="p-1 text-center" colspan="4">No result found</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
            <?= $pager->makeLinks($page, $perPage, $total, 'custom_view') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <?= $this->endSection() ?>
```

my custom view is

```
  <!-- Limit to 3 Links each side of the current page -->
  <?php $pager->setSurroundCount(3)  ?>
  <!-- END-->

  <div class="row">
  <!-- Pagination -->

 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <ul class="pagination">
        <!-- Previous and First Links if available -->
        <?php if($pager->hasPrevious()): ?>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="<?= $pager->getFirst() ?>" class="page-link">First</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="<?= $pager->getPrevious() ?>" class="page-link">Previous</a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- End of Previous and First -->

        <!-- Page Links -->
        <?php foreach($pager->links() as $link): ?>
            <li class="page-item <?= $link['active'] ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a class="page-link" 
  href="<?= $link['uri'] ?>"><?= $link['title'] ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <!-- End of Page Links -->

        <!-- Next and Last Page -->
        <?php if($pager->hasNext()): ?>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="<?= $pager->getNext() ?>" class="page-link">Next</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="<?= $pager->getLast() ?>" class="page-link">Last</a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- End of Next and Last Page -->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Pagination -->

  <!-- Pagination Details -->
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <?php if($total_res > 0): ?>
    <div class="fw-light fs-italic text-muted text-end">Showing <?= (($page * $perPage) - 
   $perPage +1) ."-". (($page * $perPage) - $perPage + ($total_res))  ?> Result out of <?= 
   number_format($total) ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
 <!-- End of Pagination Details -->
 </div>
```

my routs are

```
  $routes->get('/', 'Dashbord::index');
  $routes->get('/loadlog', 'Dashbord::loadlog');
  $routes->match(['post'], '/login', 'Dashbord::loadlog');


  $routes->group('/Main', ['filter'=>'authented'], static function($routes){
    $routes->get('', 'Main::index');
    $routes->get('(:segment)', 'Main::$1');
    $routes->get('(:segment)/(:any)', 'Main::$1/$2');
    
  $routes->match(["get", "post"], "edit-customer/(:num)", "Customer::editCustomer/$1");
 });
```

Comment: the URL for the first page is " http://localhost/plab/public/Main/customers"  and the URL for second page is   " http://localhost/plab/Main/customers?page=2"

Answer (score 0):

actually there was an error in my base url i was using public folder of codeigniter 4 but i was not including it in my base url initially i used base url http://localhost/plab/ but now i changed to  http://localhost/plab/public/  after this now i am getting all pages